# Select Product Where Price Is Greater Than Zero

Tags: database, module, magento-1

Given the following code:

```
$mageProductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addPriceData()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1')
                    );
```

How would I select only those products where price is greater than **X**? I have tried several things, including the following:

```
$mageProductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addPriceData()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('price', array('gt' => '0.00')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1')
                    );
```

But I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 0));` instead of

`addFieldToFilter('price', array('gt' => '0.00')`

Comment: Note that this will not handle calculated prices from discounts.

Answer (score 4):

The use of addAttributeToFilter is required:

```
$mageProductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addPriceData()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => '0.00')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1')
                    );
```